# Raspberry Pi4 USB3 SSD

Tags: pi-4, usb3

I have tried different SATA-SSDs with USB to SATA connectors.
Afar from the multiple questions in this forum my question is quite simple:
Why do connectors with SSDs work flowlessly on one desktop and one laptop (both openSuse 15.3),
but have multiple flaws with (new) raspian on Pi4 ?
Problems are :

cannot use uos

no fstrim

bad read and write speeds.
So it seems for me, the problem is with raspian or the hardware of Pi4.
I have not tried USB2, because I don't expect improving speed with USB2.

Comment: Have you tried a search using the exact error message you received? My experience is similar to yours: I've had good luck with the adapters on my laptops, though I've never tried one on the RPi.  Have you tried both the USB 2 & the USB 3 ports on the RPi?

Comment: Check that the power supply you are using for the PI4 can provide enough power.

Comment: Not the question I asked, of course I tried a USB3 hub

Comment: What is your Pi kernel version and does it have `CONFIG_USB_UAS`?

Comment: it depends on the chip in the cable